# Jquery calculate rows and columns

Tags: jquery

[image]

I want to calculate rows and columns but there is an error and I cant solve it. Script calculate column is true but rows are false what is wrong? How can do this?

```
    <table id="dataTable" class="stripe row-border order-column" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">TOPLAM DATA</th>
                <th id="toplamData">{{ $totalData }}</th>
                <th colspan="3" rowspan="2">2 AYLIK DATA SONUÇLARI</th>
                <th colspan="5" rowspan="2">BU AY</th>
                <th colspan="4" rowspan="2">BUGÜNKÜ DATA HEDEFİ</th>
                @foreach ($trainings as $training)
                <th style="text-align:center" colspan="5">{{ $training->name }}</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">GİDEN DATA</th>
                <th>{{ $assignedData }}</th>
                @foreach ($trainings as $training)
                <th style="text-align:center" colspan="3">GELEN DATA ADETİ</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">{{ Helper::getTrainingSiteDataCount($training->id) }}</th>
                <th style="text-align:center">{{ Helper::getTrainingReklamDataCount($training->id) }}</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">KALAN DATA</th>
                <th>{{ $totalData - $assignedData }}</th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">2 AYLIK DATA ADETİ</div></th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">2 AYLIK SATIŞ ADETİ</div></th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">ORAN</div></th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">SIRALAMA</div></th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">DATA</div></th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">SATIŞ</div></th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">NET SATIŞ</div></th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">ORAN</div></th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">DAĞITIM ADETİ</div></th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">SİTE</div></th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">REKLAM</div></th>
                <th rowspan="2"><div class="vertical">KALAN</div></th>
                @foreach ($trainings as $training)
                <th colspan="3">KALAN DATA ADETİ</th>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>20</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>S.NO</th>
                <th>AD SOYAD</th>
                <th>OFİS</th>
                @foreach ($trainings as $training)
                <th>DATA</th>
                <th>SATIŞ</th>
                <th>ORAN</th>
                <th>SİTE</th>
                <th>REKLAM</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($salesmans as $salesman)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                <td>{{ $salesman->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $salesman->branch->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ Helper::getStaffAssignedDataLastTwoMonth($salesman->id) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Helper::getStaffSalesLastTwoMonth($salesman->id) }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ Helper::getStaffAssignedData($salesman->id) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Helper::getStaffSales($salesman->id) }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input class="alacagiToplamDataSayisi" type="number" min="0" style="width: 50px;"></td>
                <td><span class="alacagiSiteDataSayisi"></td>
                <td><span class="alacagiReklamDataSayisi"></td>
                <td><span class="kalanDataHakki"></td>
                @foreach ($trainings as $training)
                <td>{{ Helper::getStaffTrainingAssignedData($salesman->id, $training->id) }}</td>
                <td>{{ Helper::getStaffTrainingSales($salesman->id, $training->id) }}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input class="verilenSiteDataSayisi" name="verilenSiteDataSayisi[{{$salesman->id}}][{{$training->id}}]" type="number" min="0" style="width: 50px;"></td>
                <td><input class="verilenReklamDataSayisi" name="verilenReklamDataSayisi[{{$salesman->id}}][{{$training->id}}]" type="number" min="0" style="width: 50px;"></td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            @endforeach
       </tbody>
       <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>TOPLAM</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span class="verilenTumDatalarToplami"></td>
            <td><span class="verilenTumSiteDatalariToplami"></td>
            <td><span class="verilenTumReklamDatalariToplami"></td>
            <td><span class="kalanTumDataHaklariToplami"></td>
            @foreach ($trainings as $training)
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span class="verilenTumSiteDataSayisi"></td>
            <td><span class="verilenTumReklamDataSayisi"></td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
       </tfoot>




$("#dataTable").on('input', '.alacagiToplamDataSayisi, .verilenSiteDataSayisi, .verilenReklamDataSayisi', function () {
    var toplamData = '<?php echo $totalData; ?>';

    var alacagiToplamDataSayisi = 0;
    var alacagiSiteDataSayisi = 0;
    var alacagiReklamDataSayisi = 0;
    var kalanDataHakki = 0;

    var verilenTumDatalarToplami = 0;
    var verilenTumSiteDatalariToplami = 0;
    var verilenTumReklamDatalariToplami = 0;
    var kalanTumDataHaklariToplami = 0;

    $(".alacagiToplamDataSayisi").each(function () {
        var getValue = $(this).val();
        if ($.isNumeric(getValue)) {
            alacagiToplamDataSayisi += parseFloat(getValue);
            verilenTumDatalarToplami += parseFloat(getValue);
        }
    });
    
    $(".verilenSiteDataSayisi").each(function () {
        var getValue = $(this).val();
        if ($.isNumeric(getValue)) {
            alacagiSiteDataSayisi += parseFloat(getValue);
            verilenTumSiteDatalariToplami += parseFloat(getValue);
        }
    });

    $(".verilenReklamDataSayisi").each(function () {
        var getValue = $(this).val();
        if ($.isNumeric(getValue)) {
            alacagiReklamDataSayisi += parseFloat(getValue);
            verilenTumReklamDatalariToplami += parseFloat(getValue);
        }
    });

    $(".kalanDataHakki").each(function () {
        var getValue = $(this).html();
        if ($.isNumeric(getValue)) {
            kalanDataHakki += parseFloat(getValue);
            kalanTumDataHaklariToplami += parseFloat(getValue);
        }
    });

    $(".verilenTumDatalarToplami").html(verilenTumDatalarToplami);
    if ($(".verilenTumDatalarToplami").html() > toplamData) {
        $(".verilenTumDatalarToplami").css("color","red").css("font-weight","bold");
    } else {
        $(".verilenTumDatalarToplami").css("color","").css("font-weight","");
    }
    $(".verilenTumSiteDatalariToplami").html(verilenTumSiteDatalariToplami);
    $(".verilenTumReklamDatalariToplami").html(verilenTumReklamDatalariToplami);
    $(".kalanTumDataHaklariToplami").html(verilenTumDatalarToplami - (verilenTumSiteDatalariToplami + verilenTumReklamDatalariToplami));
    if ($(".kalanTumDataHaklariToplami").html() <0) {
        $(".kalanTumDataHaklariToplami").css("color","red").css("font-weight","bold");
    } else {
        $(".kalanTumDataHaklariToplami").css("color","").css("font-weight","");
    }
    $(".alacagiSiteDataSayisi").html(alacagiSiteDataSayisi);
    $(".alacagiReklamDataSayisi").html(alacagiReklamDataSayisi);
    $(".kalanDataHakki").html(alacagiToplamDataSayisi - (alacagiSiteDataSayisi + alacagiReklamDataSayisi));
    if ($(".kalanDataHakki").html() <0) {
        $(".kalanDataHakki").css("color","red").css("font-weight","bold");
    } else {
        $(".kalanDataHakki").css("color","").css("font-weight","");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please do read the [tour] and [ask].  You've included quite a bit of code, please read [mcve] to keep the code to the *relevant* parts (maybe it is all relevant, but seems a lot).  You could also benefit from create a snippet ([edit] and click `[<>]`), see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for more info.

Comment: Finally, please see [it's not working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) and see if you can provide more details regarding what's the actual issue is *"rows are false"* is unclear